# Merge method created copy in case of transient instance

Tags: hibernate

Consider a scenario I have a detached entity instance and if I fetch another row with same database identifier as like detached entity from database, so now I have a detached instance and a managed instance and both corresponds to the same database row. Now a if I try to merge the detached instance and instead of creating copy, if the same detached instance is made managed then it will leave existing reference to the managed instance in inconsistent state. So a confusion is there about what needs to be done with the instance that is already there in Persistent context, so to avoid this merge method copies the state of detached in managed instance and returns the managed instance.

This is fine but now this leads to a question why a transient instance is not made managed directly, why a copy is needed in case of transient instance?

Comment: @Pascal Thivent can you please give some insight over this?

Comment: It's not always absolutely needed, but it makes the `merge()` method more consistent, easier to use, and thus causes less bugs: It **never** makes the passed entity managed. It **always** creates/modify another, managed entity.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah, your right! this can be reason. But it was just in my mind that a copy is not needed in case of transient instance. But cool it means to make the method perform consistently for all type of instances it returns copy.